# ADT installation Error

Tags: android

I am using Eclipse 3.5 (Galileo), and I'm trying to install ADT plugin from remote as well as local archive.
It is  not installing. 
I am getting the following error for both remote as well local:

```
Android Development Tools 0.9.5.v200911191123-20404 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 0.9.5.v200911191123-20404)
Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 0.9.5.v200911191123-20404 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 0.9.5.v200911191123-20404) requires 'org.eclipse.gef 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

How do I solve this?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install the eclipse [graphical editing framework](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/). You can install directly from within eclipse using the release site

http://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates/releases/

Answer (score 0):

I just went through the experience of installing the Android SDK and ADT Plugin.  Below is a link to how to setup the ADT Plug-in.

ADT Plug-in Installation:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to install eclipse INDIGO version, That contains every requirements you met. Good luck.

Something I have to say is: INDIGO is much more faster than galileo!! So upgrade it without hesitate!